# Google-like online installer and updater using NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis, updates, download

I would like create Google-like online installer and updater using NSIS.
What plugins should I use?
And maybe somebody can recommend any existing solutions or examples?

Comment: Can you show an example of this Google on-line installer?

Comment: For example Google Chrome online installer (https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/eula.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Inetc plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in) to download files, it can also perform HEAD requests if you want to perform the version check on the server. Everything else really depends on your specific setup but creating multi-stage online installers/updaters is not easy; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233960/3501) for a list of things you need to think about/figure out...